# "An error occured while communicating to the server." - using Jtables

Tags: mysqli, jtable

I am trying to use the "**Using jTable with PHP**" sample http://www.jtable.org/Home/Downloads, but when I run the program and changed "mysql" functions to "mysqli", I can't connect to the database and got the error: "An error occured while communicating to the server"

I am new with using mysqli, I tried to search all day but ended up with nothing.

jTableSimplePagedSorted.php

```
<html>
  <head>

    <link href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Scripts/jtable/themes/lightcolor/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="PeopleTableContainer" style="width: 600px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Prepare jTable
            $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 2,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=list',
                    createAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=create',
                    updateAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=update',
                    deleteAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    PersonId: {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: false
                    },
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Author Name',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    Age: {
                        title: 'Age',
                        width: '20%'
                    },
                    RecordDate: {
                        title: 'Record date',
                        width: '30%',
                        type: 'date',
                        create: false,
                        edit: false
                    }
                }
            });

            //Load person list from server
            $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

        });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

PersonActionsPagedSorted.php

```
<?php

try
{
    //Open database connection
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "jtabletestdb");

    //Getting records (listAction)
    if(isset($_GET["action"]) || "list")
    {
        //Get record count
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM people;");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $recordCount = $row['RecordCount'];

        //Get records from database
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY " . $_GET["jtSorting"] . " LIMIT " . $_GET["jtStartIndex"] . "," . $_GET["jtPageSize"] . ";");

        //Add all records to an array
        $rows = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
        $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
    }
    //Creating a new record (createAction)
    else if(isset($_GET["action"]) == "create")
    {
        //Insert record into database
        $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO people(Name, Age, RecordDate) VALUES('" . $_POST["Name"] . "', " . $_POST["Age"] . ",now());");

        //Get last inserted record (to return to jTable)
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE PersonId = LAST_INSERT_ID();");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['Record'] = $row;
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
    }
    //Updating a record (updateAction)
    else if(isset($_GET["action"]) == "update")
    {
        //Update record in database
        $result = mysqli_query("UPDATE people SET Name = '" . $_POST["Name"] . "', Age = " . $_POST["Age"] . " WHERE PersonId = " . $_POST["PersonId"] . ";");

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
    }
    //Deleting a record (deleteAction)
    else if(isset($_GET["action"]) == "delete")
    {
        //Delete from database
        $result = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM people WHERE PersonId = " . $_POST["PersonId"] . ";");

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        print json_encode($jTableResult);
    }

    //Close database connection
    mysqli_close($con);

}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    //Return error message
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "ERROR";
    $jTableResult['Message'] = $ex->getMessage();
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to connect to a database:
    mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
Here is a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp) to the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
//Open database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con, "jtabletestdb");

//Getting records (listAction)
if(isset($_GET["action"]) || "list")
{
    //Get record count
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM people;"); //just add $con
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $recordCount = $row['RecordCount'];

    //Get records from database
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY " . $_GET["jtSorting"] . " LIMIT " . $_GET["jtStartIndex"] . "," . $_GET["jtPageSize"] . ";"); //just add $con

    //Add all records to an array
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```